# Angular 2 - [Object Object] - Access the property of the object using dot notation does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know in Angular there are two ways to access object values

Access the property of the object using dot notation (obj.property).
Access the property of the object by passing in key value for example obj["property"]

If I output {{ page | json }} , I get an object with all the list.

[image]

If I do *' page.id '* or any property I get an error:

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./PageSingleComponent class PageSingleComponent - inline template:3:6 caused by:
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'self.context.page.id')

My component is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from '../page';
import { PageService } from '../page.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-single',
  templateUrl: './page-single.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-single.component.css'],
  providers: [PageService]
})
export class PageSingleComponent implements OnInit {

  page: Page;

  constructor( private pageService: PageService, private route: ActivatedRoute ) { }




  getPost(slug){
  console.log('page slug is',slug);
    this.pageService
      .getPost('other-page')
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.page = res[0];
         console.log('posts inside', res, slug);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
       let pageSlug = params['pageSlug'];
       this.getPost(pageSlug)
    });

  }

}
```

Page service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Page } from './page';

@Injectable()
export class PageService {

  private _wpBase = "http://ecommerce-ux.london/wp-json/wp/v2/";

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.http = http
    this.getPost().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log('posts', data)

        },
        (err) =>  console.log("Error Loging In:",err),
        () => { console.log("All Good With The posts Data")  }
      );




  }

  getPages(): Observable<Page[]> {

      return this.http
        .get(this._wpBase + 'pages')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  getPost(pageSlug): Observable<Page> {

      return this.http
       .get(this._wpBase + `pages?slug=${pageSlug}`)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());

  }

}
```

Page-single.component.html

```
<div>
   <!-- {{ page | json }} works -->
  <h1>{{ page.id  }}</h1>

</div>
```

Console.log 
[image]

Comment: which line of code in the question causes the error ... i see no `page.id` in the code ... `Uncaught (in promise)` - no promises in your code either

Comment: updated my comment with console log and the html

Comment: are you sending any input parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `page` property of your component is not assigned a default value it’s not actually defined until the `subscribe` callback in `PageSingleComponent.getPost` sets it. This causes an error because you can’t access the `id` property of `undefined` since it's not an object.

To fix this you need to avoid evaluating the template expression until `page` has been set. You can do this via `ng-if`:

```
<h1 *ngIf=“page”>{{ page.id  }}</h1>
```

Or you can use the safe navigation operator:

```
<h1>{{ page?.id  }}</h1>
```

Comment: That's actually `<h1>{{ page?.id  }}</h1>` - Elvis operator (question mark) comes before the dot.

Comment: Can you correct please your reply with <h1 *ng-if=“page”>{{ page.id  }}</h1> to <h1 *ngIf=“page”>{{ page.id  }}</h1> and thank you for the clarification. PS. you are a star! took me 4hrs to figure out,.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs No problem. And sorry for the syntax goofs.